# python: Difference between operation sorted(set(array)) vs set(sorted(array))

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, set

I was solving a question on Hacker rank when I came across a strange behavior.

Lists generated from following 2 pieces of code should be same.

```
#array is list containing random elements
#method 1
array1 = list(set(sorted(array)))

#method 2
array2 = sorted(set(array))

#Hence following line of code should return True
array1 == array2
```

However, depending on the size of the list the answer is different.
If the size of list if small, lets say 10 elements then that line of code returns True. However, if the list is sufficiently long that statement returns False.

I wanted to understand what is going on behind the scenes as logically in both the cases the answer should be True.

Examples 1:

```
In [60]: array                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[60]: [9, 8, 5, 0, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1, 3]

In [61]: sorted(set(array)) == list(set(sorted(array)))                                                                                                                                        
Out[61]: True
```

Example 2:

```
In [103]: import requests                                                                                                                                                                      

In [104]: link = "https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/70945/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1591229125&Signature=ocC7OZJJVIxAI00bzLNu73T%2BZTk%3D&response-
     ...: content-type=text%2Fplain"                                                                                                                                                           

In [105]: ipstring = requests.get(link).content.decode("utf-8")                                                                                                                                

In [106]: a = list(map(int, ipstring.split("\n")[2].split()))                                                                                                                                  

In [107]: sorted(set(a)) == list(set(sorted(a)))                                                                                                                                               
Out[107]: False
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have given Minimal reproducible example. Please read the examples provided in the question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
I have updated the question, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, logically, it *shouldn't* be True.

```
sorted(set(a)) == list(set(sorted(a)))
```

On the right-hand side, you sort your list, then you call `set` on it, which **loses the order**, you then create a list out of it, which *gives you some arbitrary order*, whereas `sorted(set(a))` will always be sorted...

For the small examples, **it just happens to be the case** that `set` preserved the order, that's because smaller, positive integers just hash to themselves.

So consider:

```
>>> data = [9, 8, 5, 0, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1, 3]
>>> data.sort()
>>> data
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(map(hash, data))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But that is an implementation detail...

Comment: Makes sense, I tried with values `[10000, 100000, 10000000, 100000000000]` and doesn't return `True`

Comment: @Anuj yep. Really, the *surprising* thing is that this ever does return True! Again, likely going to only happen with things like `int` objects where the order of the objects is somewhat preserved by the hash function. Any other time it would just be sheer luck